# Prevent WPF TextBox from displaying on multiple lines

Tags: wpf, word-wrap

I have a WPF TextBox intended to accept a search term and do something with that search term when the user hits the Enter key (with the TextBox focused).

For unexplained reasons, that TextBox allows for multiple lines of text to be entered.

I have set `TextWrapping` to `NoWrap` and `MaxLines` to `1`.  The associated event handler indicates that it handles the event when Environment.NewLine terminates the text.

Except for the wrapping, everything else is working as expected.  How can I prevent the text wrapping?

```
<TextBox Height="23" Margin="24,1,12,0" Name="txtSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="Visible" MinWidth="50" LostFocus="txtSearch_LostFocus" AcceptsReturn="True" TextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" MaxLines="1" />


private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearch.Text.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
    {
        string search = txtSearch.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
        e.Handled = true;

        MainViewModel vm = (MainViewModel)this.FindResource("viewModel");
        vm.SearchText = search;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean it Wraps when you hit Enter? Or when the Text gets too long?

You have `AcceptsReturn="True"`, which means the user can use the Enter key inside your TextBox to create a newline. Try setting it to False instead.

Comment: @Eric J. You would hook up an event to the TextBox's `PreviewKeyDown`, and if the Key pressed was the Enter key, you would handle the search.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using text changed event you can use previewkeydown or previewkeyup events...

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
         e.Handled = true;
         // handle search here
    } 
    else
    {
        // do some thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `AcceptsReturn` to false, not true. Setting it to true means that it is an acceptable text input.

Comment: I want the enter key to cause the search to begin (i.e. trigger my event handler, rather than be passed on to the form).  However, I want to prevent that input from reaching the TextBox.  I thought that by indicating the event is handled, that would happen.  How can I trigger my event handler when the Enter key is pressed, but prevent that input from reaching the TextBox?